# Flutter web get screen size

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I first time try flutter for web and build a project on top off existing project according to this documentation https://flutter.dev/web. Project run fine  but in chrome half off my application is out off screen. I tried to get screen size with MediaQuery.of(context) and SafeArea() but nothing happens. What is right way to get screen size?

Comment: MediaQuery is the correct solution

Comment: Can you share how you use MediaQuery? It should work

Comment: would love to see the code on this one.

Comment: As @RémiRousselet mentioned MeadiaQuery should do the trick. I use it in my web application quite often and can confirm it works well. Maybe if you post some simple example where it doesn't work, it could help. Just to be sure, hope you are using the [Size](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/size.html) attribute as in here and utilizing the corresponding [width and height](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Size-class.html) of the same.

Comment: I can confirm that MediaQuery works.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter, I've been attempting to determine the size of the entire context view. You may get `width` or `height` by using `MediaQuery` with the current context of your widget

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Around your widget, you'll need a `MaterialApp` or a `WidgetsApp`. They are the ones who give the `MediaQuery`. Flutter will always look up the widget tree to find the widget when you call`.of(context)`.

You can Improve responsiveness by adding Functions like

```
static bool isSmallScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 800;
  }
  static bool isLargeScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 1200;
  }
  static bool isMediumScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 800 &&
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 1200;
  }
```

In my opinion, don't use a garbage library that doesn't support multiplatform and don't have above 100 pub points instead of create your own functions to do stuff and also you can use `expand` which expand the screen according to the screen size

don't give size like

```
height:100
weight:100
```

it may lead to screen crashing when we use it on multiple screen